# Custom Adapter ListView strange behaviour

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I want to implement a listview were you can search for items and click on them. Here everything works fine. Now I have some items in the view were I want to set the alpha value to make them look like they cant be clicked.
To show the problem I reduced my function to just set the alpha value to items were some variable called "rezept_groesse" equals "Snack". This String is also shown on the list view.
So my task for now: Reduce the alpha value for items were "rezept_groesse" equals "Snack". Doesnt sound very complicated, but I get some strange behaviour:
I created a custom Base Adapter and in "getView" I set the Text of the items (TextViews) an also the alpha value like this:

```
    if(spannableString_groesse.toString().equals("Snack")){
        holder.rezept_name_search.setAlpha(0.2f);
    }

    holder.rezept_name_search.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

But the alpha value isn't set only for the "Snack" values but also for some other ones:

[image]

as you can see not only for "Snack" the alpha value is reduced, but also for "kleine Mahlzeit", but not always.

If I scroll the ListView up and down for some times, one after another, the alpha value of all listview items gets reduced, doesn't matter which value "mahlzeit_groesse" has: 
[image]

Maybe someone has an explanation for this problem?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show me your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem now. My mistake was to not reset the alpha value while scrolling. So after a while the alpha value of every element gets set to 0.2f. 
The code had to be changed to something like this:`

```
if(spannableString_groesse.toString().equals("Snack")){
    holder.rezept_name_search.setAlpha(0.2f);
}else{
    holder.rezept_name_search.setAlpha(1.0f);
}

holder.rezept_name_search.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```